# conditional jump on un-initialized values

Tags: c++, string, pointers, valgrind

I have a test function

```
std:string tmp(length * 2, 'a');
int len = tmp.length();
char *ptr = new char[len + 1];
strncpy(ptr, tmp.c_str(), len);
ptr[len + 1] ='\0';

data_log(ptr);
delete ptr;
```

I am getting valgrind error

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) on line data_log(ptr)
```

I have tried various options but failed. Please anyone help?

Comment: `ptr[len] ='\0'`

Comment: `ptr[len + 1] ='\0'` is undefined behavior. You exceed the bounds of the array. The last element in an array of size `N` is `N - 1`. In this case it's `ptr[len]`.

Comment: Why do you use the char array at all?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of wheel-spinning. Just call `data_log(tmp.c_str());`.